# stale element references in loop after redirection to another page

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, protractor, e2e-testing

i am trying to choose a certain element of similar objects on a website, in my e2e tests, and to click it then to change to another site, related to that element. The Problem is that the loop is still going on after the page is changed because the promise resolves asynchronous (i'm new to all this stuff)

Here the code:

```
    goToCartridge(name){
    let done = false;
    element(by.id('dashboard')).all(by.className('card z-depth-1')).then( elems => {
      for(let i = 0; i < elems.length ; i++ ){
        if(done) break;
          elems[i].element(by.tagName('h2')).getText().then( text => {
            if(name === text) {
              element(by.id('cartridge-' + i)).click();
              done = true;
            }
          return;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

How can i wait for the async part inside the loop before the next iteration starts? i searched alot for a solution, but couldnt find one yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can skip the loop of elems and call check next element of elems from inside gettext() callback like this

```
goToCartridge(name){
    let done = false;
    element(by.id('dashboard')).all(by.className('card z-depth-1')).then( elems => {
    function check(i) {
      if( i >= elems.length ) return;
      elems[i].element(by.tagName('h2')).getText().then( text => {
        if(name === text) {
          element(by.id('cartridge-' + i)).click();
        }
        else {
          check(i+1);
        }
      });
    }
    check(0);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to rewrite to something like this:

```
goToCartridge(name) {
    $$('#dashboard .card.z-depth-1 h2').each((card, index) => {
        card.getText().then(text=> {
            if (name === text) {
                $(`cartridge-${index}`).click()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works, I changed the for loops to array.map and filter. Not sure if Array.from is going to work on elms:

```
goToCartridge(name){
  element(by.id('dashboard')).all(by.className('card z-depth-1'))
  .then( 
    elems => {
      Promise.all(
        Array.from(elems).map(
          element =>
            element.element(by.tagName('h2')).getText()
            .then( text => [text,element] )
        )
      ).then(
        result=> {
          let [_,index] = result.map(
            ([text,element],index)=>[name === text,index]
          ).filter(
            ([hasText,index])=>hasText
          )[0];
          if(index !== undefined){
            return element(by.id('cartridge-' + index)).click();
          }
          else{
            return Promise.reject("could not find element");
          }
        }
      )
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you can try to call .getText() on - `element(by.id('dashboard')).all(by.className('card z-depth-1')).getText()` 
Which will return promise that will be resolved to array of strings

Comment: @Xotabu4 I don't know about that but it would make the whole thing a lot shorter. What does protractor use? Is it nightmare with selenium or something else?

Comment: Protractor uses official WebdriverJS bindings inside, but provides some extensions for elements - like ElementFinder and ElementArrayFinder  - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder